# How to Convert MonthCalendar to Bitmap in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net

In Windows Form, I would like to generate a calendar (in month view), I would choose the month, and then I would like to generate an image I could save.

I know MonthCalendar control, I know how it works but I don't know how to get the image programatically. (of course, screengrabs are useless here, ;-)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy with the Control.DrawToBitmap() method.  This worked fine:

```
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(monthCalendar1.Width, monthCalendar1.Height);
  Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
  monthCalendar1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, rc);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about Control.DrawToBitmap method